# compare -999 in type double in Java with == and .equals()

Tags: java

**Edit**: Some people stated that this is possible duplicate of one of question asking how to compare string values. I was asking about comparing double with int, that is why .equal() did not work.

---

First, I set a LinkedList of doubles with first element = -999

then if the comparison is

```
return listOfNumber.getFirst().equals(-999);
```

the outcome will be false.

However if the comparison is written as

```
return listOfNumber.getFirst()== -999;
```

Then the outcome will be true.

**I thought .equals() compares the value and == compare the object and == can only take -128 to 127. So why exactly I cannot use .equals to compare doubles?**

Also if the LinkedList is String with first element = "a"
if I use

```
return ListOfString.getFirst() == "a";
```

then the outcome is false
but if I use

```
return ListOfString.getFirst().equals("a");
```

then the outcome is true.

I am very confused why the comparison of double and string need to be different to yield correct result?

Comment: When comparing primitives you have to use `==`, if you are comparing objects you have to use `.equals()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: The first example fails cause `-999` is an `int`. `getFirst` returns a `Double`, whose `equals` methods requires `(obj instanceof Double)`. You can fix this by prefixing your number with `d`: `list.getFirst().equals(-999d)`

Comment: I suspect [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) being at the core of this problem. Could you try `return -999 == listOfNumber.getFirst();`?

Comment: @Turing85 That returns `true`, same as his example of `list.getFirst() == -999`

Comment: Regarding the edit... `ListOfString.getFirst()` should **always** use `.equals`... Unless that's actually a list of numbers, not Strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is caused by autoboxing in Java.

Assuming (as you stated `listOfNumber` is a list of Double`):

```
ArrayList<Double> listOfNumber = new ArrayList<>();
listOfNumber.add(-999);
```

Since Java knows the signature of `... add(T)` is `... add(Double)`, your add statement gets translated to:

```
listOfNumber.add(Double.valueOf(-999));
```

When you are executing

```
return listOfNumber.getFirst().equals(-999);
```

Java knows that `Object.equals` accepts a `Object`, and -999 fits an integer (the default type for a number), so it translates it to:

```
return listOfNumber.getFirst().equals(Integer.valueOf(-999));
```

Since a Integer and a Double aren't the same, it returns false, but for the `==` case, the java compilers gets smarter, and knows `(double)-999 == (integer)-999`

Comment: "*java compilers gets smarter, and knows (double)-999 == (integer)-999*" This is not the case. The compiler will promote the integer to a double, so it wouldn't be "smart enough" to simply compare the two, rather it changes the representation of one of them to match. Check out [§5.6 Numeric Promotions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6)., more specifically, [§5.6.2 Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)